# Firefox Add-on dev , How to use sample code from MDN in Addon Builder

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using add on builder to build extensions when searching MDN I find interfaces that I can't figure how to call them in online addon builder

for example this code

```
var bmsvc = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-bookmarks-service;1"]
                      .getService(Components.interfaces.nsINavBookmarksService);
```

doesn't build and results in XPI error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the top of your document put line:

```
const { Cc, Ci, Cu } = require('chrome');
```

and instead of `Components.classes` try using `Cc`, instead of `Components.interfaces` try `Ci`.

```
var bmsvc = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-bookmarks-service;1"]
                  .getService(Ci.nsINavBookmarksService);
```

This should work, if not, put link to your public addon or sample of code and link to documentation site.

Comment: Thanks i'll test this when I get home ;)